Cloud Function in Google Cloud works in Testing but not after deployment
I am a beginner when it comes to cloud platforms. I am trying to create a cloud function in google cloud, with an HTTP trigger, where, given an image url as argument, it is supposed to download it and get the results of an image classification model that I trained previously in Tensorflow, and that I saved in a bucket, along with a text file containing the possible model outputs.
The model works fine and just like I want it to when I use the Testing feature in the Google Cloud interface, as you can see here:

However, after actually deploying the Cloud Function, I can't get it to work as it is supposed to when using the browser... It always yields a 500 Internal error if I write something like this, for example, into the address bar of my browser:
https://myprojectandfunction.net/function-1?url=https://www.zooplus.pt/magazine/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/gatos_apartamento_1.jpeg (this is not the actual cloud function url, just an example)
Despite this, using the testing function in the Google Cloud Interface still works as expected even after deployment, when I use the arguments in the image above {'url': 'www.someimage.com'}
The code for the Cloud Function is this:
import functions_framework

import requests
import os
from PIL import Image
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()
bucket_url = 'justsomebucketname'
model_file = 'model.tflite'
label_file = 'dict.txt'

bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_url)
blob_model = bucket.blob(model_file)
blob_label = bucket.blob(label_file)
blob_model.download_to_filename("model.tflite")
blob_label.download_to_filename("dict.txt") # Getting the model and labels I will need from my bucket

# This class is just the model I need for classification
class Model:

    def __init__(self, model_file, dict_file):
        with open(dict_file, 'r') as f:
            self.labels = [line.strip().replace('_', ' ') for line in f.readlines()]
        self.interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=model_file)
        self.interpreter.allocate_tensors()
        self.input_details = self.interpreter.get_input_details()
        self.output_details = self.interpreter.get_output_details()
        self.floating_model = self.input_details[0]['dtype'] == np.float32
        self.height = self.input_details[0]['shape'][1]
        self.width = self.input_details[0]['shape'][2]

    def classify(self, file, min_confidence):
        with Image.open(file).convert('RGB').resize((self.width, self.height)) as img:
            input_data = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
            if self.floating_model:
                input_data = (np.float32(input_data) - 127.5) / 127.5
            self.interpreter.set_tensor(self.input_details[0]['index'], input_data)
            self.interpreter.invoke()
            output_data = self.interpreter.get_tensor(self.output_details[0]['index'])
            model_results = np.squeeze(output_data)
            top_categories = model_results.argsort()[::-1]
            results = []
            for i in top_categories:
                if self.floating_model:
                    confidence = float(model_results[i])
                else:
                    confidence = float(model_results[i] / 255.0)
                if min_confidence != None and confidence < min_confidence:
                    break
                results.append(dict(label=self.labels[i], confidence='%.2f'%confidence))
            return results

# Here I just edited the basic template for HTTP cloud functions, given by google cloud
@functions_framework.http
def hello_http(request):
    """HTTP Cloud Function.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): The request object.
        <https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#incoming-request-data>
    Returns:
        The response text, or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using `make_response`
        <https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.make_response>.
    """
    request_json = request.get_json(silent=True)
    request_args = request.args

    if request_json and 'url' in request_json:
        url = request_json['url'] # extract the url from the request
        response = requests.get(url) # get the image data from the url
        with open('image.jpg', 'wb') as imagem:
          imagem.write(response.content) # create a jpg file with the data
        tf_classifier = Model(model_file, label_file) # instantiate the classifier
        results = tf_classifier.classify('image.jpg', min_confidence=0.01) # get the model results
        string = "According to the model, your image corresponds to, in descending order of confidence:\n"
        for r in results:
          string += f"\t {r['label']}, with a confidence of {r['confidence']};\n" # Generate a sentence that summarizes the classification results
    elif request_args and 'url' in request_args:
        url = request_json['url']
        response = requests.get(url)
        with open('image.jpg', 'wb') as imagem:
          imagem.write(response.content)
        tf_classifier = Model(model_file, label_file)
        results = tf_classifier.classify('image.jpg', min_confidence=0.01)
        string = "According to the model, your image corresponds to, in descending order of confidence:\n"
        for r in results:
          string += f"\t {r['label']}, with a confidence of {r['confidence']};\n"
    else:
        string = 'You didn't supply a url... Try again!'
    return string


When using the browser, according to the logs in Google Cloud, the 500 internal error comes from a TypeError where url = request_json['url'] is None Type and not subscriptable. But this doesn't happen in testing...
What request do I have to do to get the same results as I do in the Google Cloud Testing interface? Is using ?url="..." in the address bar wrong? Is there any other way I can get the expected results, like using curl or the python requests package?


Is using ?url="..." in the address bar wrong?

Yes, it's wrong for your code.
Your testing is sending a JSON payload to the function, and your code is parsing that payload using request.get_json(silent=True).  That's not the same thing as using a URL query string parameter.
If you want to accept a URL query string parameter, read this:

Passing Variables To Google Cloud Functions

You should use request.args.get('url') for that.
If you want to keep using a JSON payload in the request, you will not be able to work that very easily in a browser, as it will not provide an easy way to type in the JSON you want to send.  But you can use curl to specify a JSON payload similar to the one in your existing testing:

How do I POST JSON data with cURL?


Oh, I see. I used the cURL, like you said, and indeed it works! I also deployed a new cloud function that uses request.args.get('url') instead, and it is exactly what I was trying (and failing) to do. Thank you so much!
The exact cURL command that worked for me was curl -X POST https://myprojectandfunction/function-1 -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"url": "https://www.zooplus.pt/magazine/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/gatos_apartamento_1.jpeg"}'
